# Open a random file with Python Script

Tags: python, random

I have a Python Script that my family uses to play a random kid's TV show on our Media Center.  My wife tells me that the program seems to favor the same selection of shows.  Is there a way to make it more random so that it picks from some different options?

Thanks in advance.

Here is what I am currently using:

```
import glob,random,os
files = glob.glob("D:\Recorded TV\Bubble Guppies*.wtv")
files.extend(glob.glob("D:\Recorded TV\Doc McStuffins*.wtv"))
files.extend(glob.glob("D:\Recorded TV\Mickey Mouse Clubhouse*.wtv"))
files.extend(glob.glob("D:\Recorded TV\Octonauts*.wtv"))
files.extend(glob.glob("D:\Recorded TV\Team Umizoomi*.wtv"))
files.extend(glob.glob("D:\Recorded TV\Jake and the Never Land Pirates*.wtv"))
files.extend(glob.glob("D:\Recorded TV\PAW Patrol*.wtv"))
files.extend(glob.glob("D:\Recorded TV\Yo Gabba Gabba*.wtv"))
files.extend(glob.glob("D:\Recorded TV\Henry Hugglemonster*.wtv"))
files.extend(glob.glob("D:\Recorded TV\Wallykazam*.wtv"))
files.extend(glob.glob("D:\Recorded TV\Dora the Explorer*.wtv"))
files.extend(glob.glob("D:\Recorded TV\Jungle Junction*.wtv"))
files.extend(glob.glob("D:\Recorded TV\Little Einstein*.wtv"))
files.extend(glob.glob("D:\Recorded TV\The Wonder Pets*.wtv"))
files.extend(glob.glob("D:\Recorded TV\WordWorld*.wtv"))
file = random.choice(files)
print "Opening file %s..." % file
cmd = "rundll32 url.dll,FileProtocolHandler \"" + file + "\""
os.system(cmd)
```

Comment: Try `random.seed()` before your `random.choice()` call. This will seed the `random` stream based on the system time (a pseudo-random value).

Comment: This seems like a probability issue more than anything else. My guess is certain shows have more episodes than others? Or is the same episode being selected more often?

Comment: There could be psychological issues here too, e.g. confirmation bias. You could consider keeping a list of recently-played episodes (or even shows) and discarding them if re-picked.

Answer (score 0):

As @paul-seeb said, there are probably more programs in one selection. I'd first randomly pick a selection and then a show there if that's what you prefer.

```
selections = [
    'Doc McStuffins',
    'Mickey Mouse Clubhouse',
    ...
    'WordWorld',
]
selection = choice(selections)
shows = glob('D:\Recorded TV\{}*.wtv'.format(selection))
show = choice(shows)
```

Comment: Thanks everyone for the great feedback.  I really like the idea of picking the selection first.  Certain shows definitely have more episodes.  My wife tells me it seems to favor about 20 episodes out of maybe 250+.  I will try the selections route and see what happens.