# Open Random TV Show Windows - Syntax Issue

Tags: python, variables, random, path

I think I am on the right track with my script to open a random Kids TV show.  However, I keep running into errors and I think it has to do with the way I am trying to use the "selection" variable in my windows path.  Please help me figure out the correct Syntax.

Thanks in advance

```
import glob
import random
import os
selections = [
    'Doc McStuffins',
    'Mickey Mouse Clubhouse',
    'Octonauts',
    'WordWorld',
    'Team Umizoomi',
    'Jake and the Never Land Pirates',
    'PAW Patrol',
    'Yo Gabba Gabba',
    'Henry Hugglemonster',
    'Wallykazam',
    'Dora the Explorer',
    'Jungle Junction',
    'Little Einstein',
    'The Wonder Pets',    
]
selection = random.choice(selections)
print (selection)
listofshows = glob.glob('D:\Recorded TV\(selection).wtv') #seems like this is where I am failing
# print (listofshows)
episode = random.choice(listofshows)
print (episode)
# cmd = "rundll32 url.dll,FileProtocolHandler \"" + episode + "\""
# os.system(cmd)
# subprocess.Popen(cmd,shell=False)
```

My current error message:

```
17:15:43      Traceback (most recent call last):
17:15:43        Python script "97", line 24, in <module>
17:15:43          episode = random.choice(listofshows)
17:15:43        File "random.pyc", line 261, in choice
17:15:43      IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: Your `listofshows` is an empty list.

Comment: Thanks! Got it figured out now! You guys rock!

Answer (score 1):

```
'D:\Recorded TV\(selection).wtv'
```

Does **not** put the string bound to `selection` into that string literal. You want:

```
'D:\Recorded TV\{0}*.wtv'.format(selection)
```

*(note also that the wild card is back!)*

Comment: `the wild card is back`?  Why `back!`?  Did it go missing for a while or something?

Comment: Yeah I definitely need the wild card. Not sure how I forgot to include it.

Comment: Shucks now I am getting this error.  Any idea what I am doing wrong now? `18:23:33      Traceback (most recent call last):
18:23:33        Python script "102", line 24, in <module>
18:23:33          episode = random.choice(listofshows)
18:23:33        File "random.pyc", line 261, in choice
18:23:33      IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: @Gerrat it was present in the OP's [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24870226/3001761)

Comment: Ah, thanks.  The world makes sense again now (ok, maybe I'm reaching a bit).